# Curl vs CPPREST

Tags: c++, libcurl, casablanca

I am trying to access an URL, using CPPREST http_client :

http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68

I am receiving response code 302 for URL- redirection.

But when i try to access the same URL using CURL, I am receiving CURLE_OK.

Below are the 2 piece of code :

> using CURL :

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl){
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)     {
        cout<<"failed";
    }
    else  {
        cout<<"success";
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

The output is : success

> using CPPREST :

```
std::string url_= "http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68";
try
{
     http_client client1(U(url_));
     uri_builder builder1(U(""));
     client1.request(methods::GET, builder1.to_string()).then([=](http_response response)
     {
        cout<<"Response code is : "<<response.status_code();
     });
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    cout<<"response :"<<e.what();
}
```

The output is :: Response code is : 302

I do not understand why the two libs are behaving differently for same URL??

**UPDATE :**

I have also tried with :

```
http_client client1(utility::conversions::to_string_t(url_));
```

and

```
http_client client1(U("http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68"));
```

and

```
http_client client1(U("http://www.20min.ch/"));
```

but the response is same 302 with cpp rest. [ for cross checking [bing example](http://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http%20Client%20Tutorial)

is working fine]

**UPDATE 2:**

The method as explained by @Matt Weber seems very helpful and legit but i am continuously getting error code : 400 for that, So I tried the below things:
I tried to set the host and port for the URL in uri_builder.

```
http_client client(U("http://www.20min.ch/rss/"));
uri_builder builder(U("/rss.tmpl"));
builder.append_query(U("type"), U("channel"));
builder.append_query(U("get"), U("68"));
builder.set_host(U("www.20min.ch"));
builder.set_port(U("80"));
client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string()).then([=](http_response response)
{
     cout<<"Received response status code: "<<response.status_code();
});
```

but still same 302.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with the Rest SDK code is the `http_client` initialization:

```
    http_client client1(U(url_));
```

The `U` macro is for use with string literals to produce something from which a `uri` can be constructed. If you're on Windows, this shouldn't compile, because the macro expansion results in `Lurl_`. Apparently whatever this results in on your system leads to a request for something that responds with a 302.

There are a couple of options. One would be to simply use the literal directly:

```
    http_client client1(U("http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68"));
```

If you want to keep the `std::string` and initialize the client from that, you can convert to a `utility::string_t` from which the `uri` can be constructed.

```
    std::string url_= "http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68";
    http_client client1(utility::conversions::to_string_t(url_));
```

Once that is done, you'll likely find that you need to call the `wait` function on the continuation from `request` in order to actually see the expected output:

```
     client1.request(methods::GET, builder1.to_string()).then([](http_response response)
     {
        cout<<"Response code is : "<<response.status_code();
     }).wait(); // ensure that the response gets processed
```

**EDIT:**

The above is relevant for building on Windows, but has nothing to do with the 302 response.

On Linux, the request results in a 302 consistently. Looking at the request and response on the wire, a request from a Windows host gets a 200 and a request from a Linux host gets a 302. The reason is that in the Linux version, the host header includes a port number, which is what triggers the server to respond with a 302.

Windows request:

```
GET /rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
User-Agent: cpprestsdk/2.8.0\r\n
Host: www.20min.ch\r\n
\r\n
```

Linux request:

```
GET /rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.20min.ch:80\r\n
User-Agent:cpprestsdk/2.8.0\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
\r\n
```

You can verify that this is the cause with wget:

`$ wget --header="Host: www.20min.ch" -S "http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68"`

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

`$ wget --header="Host: www.20min.ch:80" -S "http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68" --max-redirect 0`

HTTP/1.1 302 Found

The difference in the header is due to the different implementations. The WinHTTP client implementation does not add the Host header explicitly, presumably because it relies on WinHTTP to do that internally. The asio client implementation does add it, though.

```
        // Add the Host header if user has not specified it explicitly
        if (!ctx->m_request.headers().has(header_names::host))
        {
            request_stream << "Host: " << host << ":" << port << CRLF;
        }
```

So to get the expected behavior, the header can be set explicitly to avoid adding the port information:

```
std::string url_= "http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68";
http_client client1(utility::conversions::to_string_t(url_));
http_request request;
request.set_method(methods::GET);
request.headers().add(U("Host"), U("www.20min.ch"));
client1.request(request).then([](http_response response)
{
    std::cout<<"Response code is : "<<response.status_code();
}).wait();
```

With this change, I get a 200 OK on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Hi.. thanks a lot, my system is waiting for the output .. this was just minimum code i wrote to explain prob. and i m comiling on linux.. i shall try ur solution and let u knw

Comment: i tried :
'http_client client1(utility::conversions::to_string_t(url_));'
but same response 302

Comment: i also tried 
  http_client client1(U("http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68")); but same response.. m building on linux

Comment: What happens if you initialize the http_client to `U("http://www.20min.ch/")`? If that returns a 200, take a look at the [Bing Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/samples/BingRequest/bingrequest.cpp) sample and try using the uri_builder for the rest of the URL like that sample does.

Comment: Okay, I believe I figured it out for real now. Edited my answer.

Comment: WOW.. thanks a lot .. i appreciate your help a lot.. but with the above code m getting error code 400. could once re-check.
I am little confused as well as the original url which i have is : 
**http://www.20min.ch/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68**
and not
**http://www.20min.ch:80/rss/rss.tmpl?type=channel&get=68**.. 
thanks again.

Comment: The 400 suggests there is something malformed about the request. Hard to say without seeing the request header. The code I included above is still working for me. The :80 in the url_ string was a mistake; I had included that when I was testing the behavior on Windows and forgot to remove it. You should not mention :80 in the URL.

Comment: Please review the update, I have made to the question

Comment: Setting the host of the URI is not the same thing as setting the host header of the HTTP request, so you are getting the 302 for the same reason as before. If you get a 400 with exactly the code that I posted, take a look at the HTTP header in a network trace. It should look like the one below "Linux Request" in my answer, with the exception of the host header, which should not include the port number.